# Karma server does not update the proxied application code

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, webstorm

I have the simple test of some angularjs services.

Let's say some test fails. I fix the code, run the test again, but the test fails again, like if the file wasn't changed.

If I go to KarmaServer tab, shut-down the server, close the "Run" session (see the screen snap) and run everything again, the changes are being applied and test succeeds.

How could I avoid this restarting?

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Well, I've just figured-out, that it is not update only "proxied" code.

It is a large app. We have got 300+ files (1 file=1 module/service/directive declaration) with 30-1200 loc in each.
And... Well.. mm... Yep! We just started to write unit tests! )

So the most simple is to just load everything like the browser does. No manual serving.
There is a file, generated by the `grunt-angular-builder`. It requires a number of files from the server and Karma proxies these requests to the real server, which is serving app (locally).
It has got some nginx directives and other stuff. Also the order matters, so it is not easy to manually write this all in the proper order for exact test suite in `<bla-bla>.conf.js` ..

Comment: Can you post your karma configuration?

Comment: are you using karma-browserify by chance? may be related to [WEB-12496](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12496)

Comment: also, does the issue occur when you change the code being tested, or the spec code? In the former case, please make sure that your code is loaded by karma (included in files[] in karma config)

Comment: @lena, Everything, except proxied code is refreshing properly. This is the problem...